# How can I downgrade npm in a nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I know this issue was declared by manyones but nothing can solve my problem.

I have tried:

- `npm uninstall  -g npm@<version>`
- `npm uninstall npm --save`
- `npm uninstall -g npm --save`

All efforts in vain. The console says something happened (a removed, refreshed or update) but if I check `npm -v` the same version of npm pops up in the console that I had before.

I need to install an older version because of the use of angular.

Can anybody give me suggestions to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

in such cases we can use nvm (Node Version Manager),
you have to install it first like any other packge.
so
to download and install a new version of node.js run

```
nvm install 7.1
```

Replace 7.1  with the version number you need.
To check what versions of node.js are installed on your system run

```
nvm ls
```

This will list out all the versions you have installed.
To switch to any node.js version you need run

```
nvm use x.x
```

(x.x version number that'S you have been installed und you want to work with)
If you do not want any particular node.js version you can uninstall it by

```
nvm uninstall x.x
```

You can set the default node.js version by setting an alias

```
nvm alias default v12.0.0
```